route param comparison is undefined (react-router-dom v6)
I running circles with this one.
Thanks in advance for all the help you could provide.
The issue is whith the way of accessing a view for a single item in an array. The id param is passed in the address and accessed with useMatch() from react-router-dom. (Edit: example bellow also shows code with the use of useParams as I tried to follow other user's use cases)
The id from the match.params seems the same as one of the items' array (as it should be)
Unfortunately, running array.find() doesn't end with a positive result, rather an undefined value.
I searched the web for details on this and maybe this is to do with v6 of the React Router ?


Doing the final exercice of the full-stack-open part 7: https://fullstackopen.com/en/part7/exercises_extending_the_bloglist#exercises-7-9-7-21


I finally ended up asking AI for debbugging but it made me check for everything I already did.
Here is the code from the  Component :
                {[...users].map(u =>
                    <tr key={u.id}>
                        <td><Link to={`/users/${u.id}`}>{u.id}</Link></td>
                        <td>{u.blogs.length}</td>
                    </tr>
                )}

Here is the App.jsx (wrapped in main.jsx by BrowserRouter) :
import { Routes, Route, Link, useParams } from 'react-router-dom'

const App = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        userService.getAll()
          .then(users => {
            setUserList(users)
            console.log('UserList:', users) // Verify the structure and content of userList
          })
          .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching users:', error))
      }, [])
    // With useMatch() //////
const userMatch = useMatch('/users/:id')
  console.log('userMatch id: ', String(userMatch.params.id))
  console.log('userList id: ', String(userList[0].id))


  const u = userMatch && userList > 0
    ? userList.find(u => String(u.id) === String(userMatch.params.id))
    : null
  console.log('User found:', u) // Log the found user


// With useParams() ////////////
    let { id } = useParams() // Get the id parameter directly
      console.log('Params ID:', id) // Log the id parameter
      console.log('UserList:', userList) // Log the userList contents
    
      const u = userList.length > 0
        ? userList.find((u) => {
          console.log('Checking user:', u.id, 'with ID:', id) // Log the comparison
          return Number(u.id) === Number(id)
        })
        : null
    
      console.log('User found:', u) // Log the found user

return (
<div>
  <div>
    <Link to='/'>Home</Link>
    <Link to='/users'>Users</Link>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h2>blogs</h2>
    <Notification notification={notification} />
    <div>
      {users.name} logged in
      <button onClick={handleLogout}>
        logout
      </button>
    </div>
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/users/:id' element={<User user={u} />} />
      <Route path='/users' element={<Users users={userList} />} />
      <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
    </Routes>

  </div>
</div>

)

Those tests were done and ok-ed :

Verify Router Setup:
Ensure that BrowserRouter (or HashRouter) is correctly wrapping your App component in the root file (index.js or equivalent):

Check URL and Routing Configuration:
Ensure the URL matches the route pattern defined in your Routes. For example, if the route is "/users/:id", the URL should be something like http://localhost:3000/users/1.

Test useParams in Isolation:
Simplify the component to directly test useParams and see if it correctly extracts the id:

Simplify App for Debugging:
Create a minimal version of App just to test routing:

Check userList Contents:
If useParams correctly extracts the id, then the issue might lie in how userList is being populated or accessed.

Cross-Verify user.id Type:
Ensure that user.id in userList matches the type of id extracted from useParams.



The bulk of this post seems irrelevant. Instead of posting all the GenAI garbage can you [edit] to just start with what the actual problem is you are facing and include a [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with?

And what is the specific problem you have in this code? Something about using the id route path parameter to find a match within an array. The id parameter appears to be alpha-numeric, so casting to Number won't work. Route path parameters are always string types, so it's better to cast your data to String for any comparisons.

You still haven't explained what the problem is you are trying to resolve.

Can you create a running Codesandbox demo of the code you are using that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live? I think you are just doing something odd elsewhere in the code. The match.params.id looks like it should match what is in your data, when it becomes available. My only guess is that because the u or user or whatever is initially null that your code is throwing an exception when it tries to access properties.

Not sure how to start the project but here is the code.
Hardcoded the array of items used to check the match.params.id
https://codesandbox.io/embed/vqh2sv?view=editor&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.jsx

The code seems to work as I'd expect it to. Here's a running sandbox with your data and components copy/pasted in.

This is puzzling.
Could it come from the imports or the child components ?

Could what.... what?! Sorry, I still don't understand what problem you are facing. You seem to be saying you can't use the id route/match parameter to search your array, but that is working as far as I can tell.

Yes, and thus my post here.
It works as expected in the sandbox, it does not when running it with Vite on my machine and the whole project.
If we take for granted that this logic snippet is correct, I am wondering where the issue is. The issue being I can't find a match for the id route param in my array of items in my browser (firefox dev ed), running my whole project.
[Appreciate the time and help you provide, just going crazy with this one]

So... TLDR: redid the project from the working logic
I started again from the sandbox code made by Drew Reese from my project: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/busy-water-2rpdcz
After moving components to their own files and adding the backend import for the userList, it still worked and I am now able to complete the exercice.
I am still puzzled to this day at what was the issue with my previous code.
